# Ansible v2.2 error when using with_subelements which worked fine in 1.7

Tags: ansible

I am getting the following error while running my ansible playbook.

> TASK [base : Rsyslog yapilandiriliyor.]
>   **************************************** fatal: [gkts.ahtapot]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check
>   'ansible_fqdn == {{item.1}}' failed. The error was: error while
>   evaluating conditional (ansible_fqdn == {{item.1}}): 'item' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/roles/base/tasks/rsyslog.yml': line 2, column 3, but
>   may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Rsyslog
>   yapilandiriliyor.\n  ^ here\n"}

This worked fine in ansible 1.7 but doesn't work in ansible 2.2.1

```
- name: Rsyslog yapilandiriliyor.
  template:
        src: "{{ rsyslog['conf']['source'] }}"
        dest: "{{ rsyslog['conf']['destination'] }}"
        owner: "{{ rsyslog['conf']['owner'] }}"
        group: "{{ rsyslog['conf']['group'] }}"
        mode: "{{ rsyslog['conf']['mode'] }}"
# when: "ansible_fqdn == item.1"
  when: "ansible_fqdn == {{item.1}}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ossimciks}}"
    - "{{clients}}"
  notify:
    - rsyslog servisini yeniden baslat
  sudo: yes
  tags: rsyslog
```

ossimciks and clients are defined in my vars file:

```
ossimciks:
   server01:
      fqdn: "OSSIMCIK_FQDN"
      port: "20514"
      clients:
        - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN"
        - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{ossimciks}}"
  - "{{clients}}"
```

### Syntax

I don't know how where/how/when this might have changed in Ansible, but I *think* that

- the first element in `with_subelements` *is a variable*, and
- the second element in `with_subelements` *is a key*.

This works in playbooks I've written, and matches [the relevant docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) (since 2.5, there are no `with_*` loops [1] in the docs since they were always lookups anyhow [2]):

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{ ossimciks }}"
  - clients
```

### Data

It's not clear to me which item you're attempting to target with `{{ item.1 }}` in your playbook, but if making a minor change to your data is permissible, you can structure it so that any of the information shown is accessible within a `with_subelements` loop (I've also expanded and restructured the data a bit to clarify what the loop is doing):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    fqdn_var: "OSSIMCIK_FQDN_2"
    ossimciks:
      - server: "server01"
        fqdn: "OSSIMCIK_FQDN_1"
        port: "20514"
        clients:
          - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_1"
          - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_2"
      - server: "server02"
        fqdn: "OSSIMCIK_FQDN_2"
        port: "20514"
        clients:
          - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_1"
          - "LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_2"

  tasks:
    - name: Output ossimciks contents.
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.server }} client: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ossimciks }}"
        - clients
      when: item.0.fqdn == fqdn_var
```

This outputs:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None)  => {"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=None)  => {"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "server02 client: LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "server02 client: LOG_KAYNAGI_FQDN_2"
}
```

---

- [1] http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html
- [2] [Loops are actually a combination of things with_ + lookup(), so any lookup plugin can be used as a source for a loop, ‘items’ is lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

---

Edited to add: the playbooks where I've used the syntax above were definitely in the 2.x release series--I think ~2.1.

Comment: I still get the same error. It seems like it can't resolve what item.1 is. BUt I don't understand why.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example that may help.